# Is there a way to be notified of an incoming ICMP-destination-unreachable message?

Tags: udp, icmp

I have an application that sends datagrams (UDP) to a server, and there is no UDP acknowledgement expected.  Many times I find that I am sending to the wrong port and would like to be able to receive the ICMP-port-unreachable response that is generated back to my machine. Is that possible with sockets in user-space?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you connect the socket. An incoming 'ICMP unreachable' will be mapped to ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: Hmmm.. does that apply to UDP (connectionless)?

Comment: @Ed. I knew someone would say that. In a word, yes. UDP is a connectionless *protocol,* but there is still a connect *operation,* which has several local side-effects such as this one. See the documentation for `connect()`.

Comment: :-)  Yep, did the reading and also tried it... Didn't get an error; hence my question.  I'll try again... Tx